# How to schedule tasks when computer is closed?

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I have python script, but my computer is closed. Is there any method which i can use task scheduler even though my computer closed, any cloud service?

Comment: You will need to be pretty specific as to what you want to do, and then someone might be able to answer you.

Comment: just I scrape a movie website, and i am getting movie name and movie year by running this python script. What i do is create a task scheduler and run this movie scrape python script to get data in every 30 minutes. To be able to make it my computer have to be open, not shut down. What i would like to make is that doing this process even though i do not use my computer and it is not working.

Comment: consider use cloud service instead, such as google cloud

Comment: does google cloud provide free trial for using their platform?

Answer (score 0):

All of the major cloud providers have some sort of cloud function.  On Azure it's called Function App, on AWS I believe it's called a lambda function.  You can essentially create a python function, deploy it to either service, and have it write the results to whatever the cheapest cloud db option they have on either service.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Any of them free? I just want to use it for educational purposes to see the results on cloud too.

Comment: Almost all of them have a free trial yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Lambda to deploy your code, AWS Cloudwatch events to trigger your application using a cron regex, and some database service. This will allow you to set the schedule to run your code on any schedule you should choose. Both cloudwatch and lambda of these services are mostly covered by the aws free tier and your usage should not cost anything.

For the database you have AWS dynamoDB for a nosql option and AWS RDS for a relation db option. I would suggest starting with dynamoDB because basic usage is covered by the free tier and it's pretty easily to get started. You could try rds, but if you are unfamiliar with it you may risk a high unintentional expense.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda + CloudWatch Rate based rule.

Python script will go in AWS Lambda

&

AWS CloudWatch rate based rule to schedule your Lambda function periodically or based on a cron expression.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html